# Mod_rewrite from Cahe and %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Evening,

I am running a file at:

/home/user/Web/sites/gubbinz/

The web server root is Web/

When I load the url: localhost/sites/gubbinz/index.php?request=home.html

I want to check to see if there is a file ./sites/gubbinz/cache/home.html

I can get this to work using the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^request=(.*)    [NC]
RewriteCond /home/user/Web/sites/gubbinz/cache/home.html -f
RewriteRule ^.+$ cache/%1 [QSA,L]
```

but not like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^request=(.*)    [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}cache/home.html -f
RewriteRule ^.+$ cache/%1 [QSA,L]
```

I prefer the latter as it would mean I can have one rule for localhost and live. Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

N.B. I do not have a RewriteBase set.

Comment: Maybe put a slash after `%{REQUEST_URI}`?

Comment: Printing the REQUEST_URI I found that it = /sites/forebears/index.php because I am doing another internal redirect to that page. The above second example will work if you don't do that.

Comment: Well, if you know that REQUEST_URI ends with index.php, then of course this isn't going to be a file: `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sites/forebears/index.phpcache/home.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some fiddling, this is the best I can come up with that works across servers without the need for multiple server conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}  ^(.+)\/index.php$                   [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=PATH:%1]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^request=(.*)    [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:PATH}/cache/%1.html -f
RewriteRule ^.+$ cache/%1.html [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.+$ index.php?request=$0 [QSA,L]
```

The first part gets the full path of the directory that the request comes from and saves it as an environmental variable. index.php is trimmed from the end.

The second part gets the internal redirect that contains the actual loaded URL, checks to see a cached version of the HTML exists and if it does carries out an internal redirect to it.

The third part takes a "search engine friendly URL" and does an internal redirect to index.php?request={URL}.

So in short, you load the url:

http://domain.com/page/sub-page

The third condition set redirect this to:

http://domain.com/index.php?request=page/sub-page

Then the second set (with the env. var. set in the first rule) sees if ./cache/page/sub-page.html exists on the server; if it does, that page is then displayed to the browser.

N.B. to anyone who may find this of use that the third condition set is not neccesary, you could do this with just two rules. I use the redirect to index.php?request=555 as part of my PHP handling.